# Excel-VBA: How to get size of selected array in vba code?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

i'm writing an vba function in excel which takes in an odd sized empty square matrix and filling it with numbers. However, I can't get to retrieve the size of the array that it dynamically selected in the spreadsheet before the function is called. How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us exactly what do you mean by `dynamically selected in the spreadsheet before the function is called.`

Comment: a wild stab in the dark:  `x = UBound(MyArray, 2)`

Answer (score 7):

Pass a Range object into your function and look at the value:

```
Public Function WhatIsTheMatrix(SourceRange as Excel.Range) As Variant

   Dim arrSource as Variant
   Dim arrOutPut as Variant

   Dim i As Long, j As Long

   arrSource = SourceRange.Value2

   i = Ubound(arrSource, 1)
   j = Ubound(arrSource, 2)

   ' The lower bounds of an array obtained from a range are always 1

   ' code
   ' more code
   ' even more code

   WhatIsTheMatrix = arrOutPut 

End Function
```

Now you have two problems:

1. Your original problem, which is solved by inspecting i and j
2. A special case, in which the value of a single-cell range isn't an array variant

So you'll need this:

```
If SourceRange.Cells.Count = 1 Then
   Redim arrSource(1 to 1, 1 To 1)
   arrSource(1,1) = SourceRange.Value2
Else
   arrSource = SourceRange.Value2
End If
```

Any other Business:

There's an unrecognized assumption, namely: you thought you could pass in the current Application.Selection and it will always be a range. It can also be a control, or a chart, or a chart series...

...And no, you can't rely on this raising a runtime error for the type mismatch. Yes, you've invoked Option Explicit and yes, you typed `SourceRange as Excel.Range` and your Mother, your Parish Priest and a Justice of the Peace watched you do it; try sacrificing something on a sinister-looking rock after midnight, and *maybe* the VBA runtime will believe you.

So you also need this:

```
If Not TypeOf SourceRange Is Excel.Range Then
   ' Raise an error or Exit Sub
End If
```

I *think* that's all the surprises. Unless you're into exotic stuff and awkward questions like "Is this range calculated?"

Comment: You might want to deal with the possibility of the selection being a `Range` with multiple `Areas`. This method will return the dimensions of the first area only (which isn't necessarily the wrong approach)